# Does every point in a system has equals moment (Torque)?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, solid-state-physics

Is there some special condition for this to be true or is this always true?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is torque independent of choice of the point of rotation?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/147932/is-torque-independent-of-choice-of-the-point-of-rotation)

Comment: I agree with Quasihorse, I find this answer https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/147942/19945 especially nice.

Answer (score 1):

Torque depends on your choice of a reference point, so no, it is not the same for every point.  However, in a static system (where there is no rotation), the sum of the torques must be zero for any chosen point.

Answer (score 0):

Yes...
Referencing the law of conservation of angular momentum, we know that the angular momentum for a body pivoted at a point is constant. Which establishes that the torque is *dL/dt*, and so torque is the same throughout (due to the inverse proportionality between linear momentum and the distance from the pivot, they cancel themselves out to give out the angular momentum of the body), i.e. it isn't directly related to the linear momentum of a particle, but is directly related to the *rotational analog* of linear momentum.