# How is group theory related to particle physics?

Tags: particle-physics, group-theory

I've always heard of such statements as $SU$ group describing our world even before I seriously learned physics.

- When learning about spin, someone spoke of $SU(2)$ but did not seriously explain.
- When learning isospin and hypercharge for particles made of $u, d, s,$ someone spoke of $SU(3)$ but did not give detailed explanation.
- When talking about the discovery of J/ψ, teacher (a experimentalist) say, well now with the charm quark, we need $SU(4)$.

I am crazy, $SU$ is just special unitary matrix group, what are they talking about when relating these matrix with spin or particles? I hope someone could give me a detailed explanation about how these group is related to real world substances or recommend a book.

Comment: I wish you would do some research on your own on this one. I googled the exact title of your question "How is group theory related to particle physics?" and there are many many results (with varying levels of mathematics) that may help you answer your very broad question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the significance of Lie groups $SO(3)$ and $SU(2)$ to particle physics?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/78536/)